# How differently are these two variables handled in memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, static

I am learning about the way memory is modeled in C. I know that there are basically four different parts. Static memory, stack, heap and program memory. I know that when something is declared static, its lifetime (and not necessarily its visibility) is the entire program. So let's say I have written something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void add();

main(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6;++i){
        add();      
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(){
    static int x=5;
    x++;
    printf("The value of x is %d\n", x); 
}
```

The program keeps track of the value of `x` till the last execution. If I write the program like this, I get pretty much the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x=5;

add(int *num){
    (*num)++;
    printf("The value of x is %d\n", *num);
}

main(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6;++i){
        add(&x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't use the `static` keyword, but because of its cope, the program keeps track of its value in successive executions of the `add()` function. I'd like to know if in both of these cases, the way `x` is handled in memory is the same. Is the second `x` also treated as static?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "static" mean in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Yes, it is. The only difference between global variables and static local variables is scope.

Comment: Then why would someone still write `static int x =5` outside of the main function? Wouldn't it be superfluous if its already static? I am sure I have seen something like that.

Comment: You have to consider a program large enough that the source code is in multiple files. In that case, a `static` variable has file scope, i.e. is not visible to code in other files. If all of the code is in *one* file, then there is no difference between a global variable (not declared `static`), and a file-scope variable (declared as `static` outside of any function).

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks. Enlightening comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the second x also treated as static?

No Second `x` is not treated as `Static`. You can still make second variable Static which would result in a different result. If second `x` is declared as `static` "scope will be limited to file" but in your case it is **NOT** limited to file.

And yes in both cases `x` lives the lifetime of the program but note the use of braces which limit the scope,

In second case `x` is only limited to scope of the function `add()`

```
void add(){  // <= From here

    static int x=5;
    x++;
    printf("The value of x is %d\n", x); 

} // <= to here
```

And for second case `x` is global and accessible from other files too.